How do I get rid of Image texture seam cuts?
I'm using the sapling tree gen add on for the tree model, as for the seamless texture I painted in krita. The texture itself has this vertical cut along the mesh, I made sure to activate shade smooth and play around with the shader, but it doesn't seem to be working how do I remove it?




In order for your tiles to meet edge-to-edge around the 0-1 V of the curve's native round bevels, there must be a whole number of tiles in V. (Mapping > Scale > Y must be a whole number) .. there are various blending workarounds.. but then your texture's tileability would be redundant.

You could convert your curve to mesh and paint the joint with the Clone brush. Another solution would be to change your material, use the Object output of the Texture Coordinate, switch the Image Texture from Flat to Box so that the texture is projected on the 3 axis (XYZ) of the object, and set the Blend to 1 to blur the joints:

